# Use of cin and getline for strings

Tags: c++, getline, cin

I was recently doing a problem in `C++`:

> Write a program to work out if a series of 5 digits are consecutive
>   numbers. To make this easier, assumes the digits are a string:
>
> string numbers = "10-9-8-7-6";
>
> Make sure your code works for the following sequence, as well:
>
> string numbers = "1-2-3-4-5";

I solved it, however I saw when I used `cin` for the string the console window threw some exception & didn't execute the program but on replacing it with `getline`, it worked perfectly.

Could anyone explain me the reason behind it because logically both should work properly.

The program is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void change(int x, int y, int &inc, int &dec)
{
    if (x - y == 1)
        ++dec;
    else if (y - x == 1)
        ++inc;
}

int main()

{
    string s = "", snum = "";
    cout << "enter 5 nos and use \'-\' to separate them: ";
    cin >> s;
    int i = 0, x = 0, y = 0, inc = 0, dec = 0;
    for (char &ch : s)
    {
        if (ch == '-')
        {
            ++i;
            if (i == 1)
            {
                y = stoi(snum);
                cout << y << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                x = y;
                y = stoi(snum);
                cout << x << " " << y << endl;
                change(x, y, inc, dec);
            }
            snum = "";
        }
        else
            snum += ch;
    }
    x = y;
    y = stoi(snum);
    cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    change(x, y, inc, dec);
    if (inc == 4 || dec == 4)
        cout << "ORDERED";
    else
        cout << "UNORDERED";
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you gave the failing code instead of the working code.

Comment: I run your code and face no problem. Can you explain your problem clearly?

Comment: just replace getline(cin,s) with cin>>s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to enter everything at the same time such as:

> 10 9 8 7 6

All on one line then `cin` does not record all that at the same time.
Concerning `cin` it only takes the characters before a space (" ") for example. `Getline` however takes that entire line and uses it. Another way to do the same thing would be to use the `cstdio library` and have it set up with either using `printf` or `puts` to prompt, and then use `gets` to gather all the information from the puts prompt. This is what I assume why it works.

Example:

cstdio library

```
char string[50];
printf("Enter a string of text");
gets(string);
cout << string << endl;
```

*EDIT

After the comment below I realized what you are asking, and if you are assuming the numbers are strings, and they are separated with hyphens and no spaces then it should work fine. It shouldn't be the problem of cin by maybe something else?

If there are spaces involved in your code then what I wrote above EDIT will be a simple solution to THAT problem.

Comment: sir, u didnt get the code properly then, it says we are entering the string as: "1-2-3-4-5" or "10-9-8-7-6" ie with a hyphen to separate the numbers. we arent using space at all, so cin should work perfectly

Comment: If they are strings then it should run fine in the compiler. That is because it doesn't take any spaces and only hyphens. If it involved spaces it would need either something else like "getline" or "gets."

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get a formatted string, I recommend you `scanf` like this:

```
if( 5 == scanf("%d-%d-%d-%d-%d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e) )
      //welldone
      // work with above 5 int easily :)
else
      // Please enter again
```

This way you don't have to work with string at all and life would be easier.
You can easily check if these 5 are consecutive or not .

If you need not a new solution and want to get your code fixed, tell me in comment.

Comment: the question asks us to assume a string sir. otherwise i wud hv definitely used your method by default (but with cin).